# DBSCAN in C++ for general and Android use

Tags: c++, performance, algorithm, android, clustering

I've implemented a templated DBSCAN for general use. At the moment, it's going to be used on Android through the JNI. I used Wikipedia's pseudocode and a little bit of the DBSCAN paper for reference. It's pretty naive, so I'm wondering how I can speed it up, and what I can do to make it perform reasonably well on a phone. How can I improve my code?

```
template <typename T>
    struct node {
        T val;
        bool visited;
        bool clustered;
        node() : visited(false), clustered(false) {}
    };

    template <typename T>
    using cluster = std::vector<T>;

    template <typename T>
    using adj_list = std::list<node<T>*>;

    template <typename T>
    using graph = std::map<node<T>*, adj_list<T>>;

    template <typename T>
    std::vector<cluster<T>> DBSCAN(T* const& dataset, size_t const& dataset_size, double const& eps, size_t const& min_pts, double(*distance_function)(T const& lhs, T const& rhs)) {

        std::vector<node<T>> node_list(dataset_size);
        for (auto i = 0; i < dataset_size; ++i) {
            node_list[i].val = dataset[i];
        }

        graph<T> g;
        for (auto i = 0; i < node_list.size(); ++i) {
            for (auto j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                if (distance_function(node_list[i].val, node_list[j].val) < eps) {
                    g[&node_list[i]].push_back(&node_list[j]);
                    g[&node_list[j]].push_back(&node_list[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        std::vector<cluster<T>> clusters;
        cluster<T> C;
        for (node<T>& n : node_list) {
            if (n.visited) continue;
            n.visited = true;
            adj_list<T> neighbour_pts = g[&n];
            if (neighbour_pts.size() >= min_pts) {
                expandCluster(n, neighbour_pts, C, g, min_pts);
                clusters.push_back(C);
                C = cluster<T>();
            }
        }

        return clusters;
    }

    template <typename T>
    void expandCluster(node<T>& point, adj_list<T>& neighbourhood, cluster<T>& C, graph<T>& g, unsigned const& min_pts) {
        C.push_back(point.val);
        point.clustered = true;
        for (node<T>*& n : neighbourhood) {
            if (!n->visited) {
                n->visited = true;
                adj_list<T> next_neighbourhood = g[n];
                if (next_neighbourhood.size() >= min_pts) neighbourhood.splice(neighbourhood.end(), next_neighbourhood);
            }
            if (!n->clustered) {
                C.push_back(n->val);
                n->clustered = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

## Naming things

Why you have all caps function name?

Why you have variable with capital letter in `expandCluster()`?
At first I thought it is template parameter i miss.

#### Use auto more often:

```
// looks ugly
for (node<T>*& n : neighbourhood) {
}

// looks better
for (auto & n : neighbourhood) {
     // adjust for * here
}

// or you can do with using
using mynode = node<T>;

// still looks better
for (mynode* & n : neighbourhood) {
}
```

## DBSCAN()

#### Make this a type:

```
template<class T>
using something = std::vector<cluster<T>>
```

#### Why you pass `dataset_size` by reference?

size_t is as big as the pointer, but there will be additional hidden dereference that will slow down the execution.
keep the const, remove `&`

```
size_t const dataset_size
```

Do the same for all non class parameters.

#### dataset

probably I am wrong, but if you type this:

```
T* const& dataset
```

like this:

```
const T* dataset
```

will be same, but more readable? Not sure what `T` is. If `T` is a container or array, why not just:

```
const CONTAINER dataset
```

#### Why you pass `C like` function pointers?

Do it with `functor` class. Or with `std::function`.

I am not very experienced with this, so I will do it with `functor`, but will add it into template parameters.

## expandCluster()

more or less similar comments.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I think I prefer to alias node<T> than to use auto as it seems a bit clearer. I had no idea that passing primitives by reference was bad practice, so thanks for that. What's the benefit of using a functor?

Comment: functor looks nicer and easier. It can have "internal" status, but I dont think this will be beneficial in your case.

Comment: One big advantage of a functor is that the called function can be expanded in line a lot more often than when you use a pointer to a function (particularly important when you're concerned with speed, as you seem to be).

Comment: i think this is correct only when functor is injected as template. if functor is injected as argument i do not see how it will be expanded.

Comment: That's interesting. What's the reason for that, Jerry?